# How do I draw a line indicating the orientation of an Apriltag?

Tags: python-3.x, rotational-matrices

I am using python and the pupils-apriltag library to detect apriltags in pictures and video. Ultimately I need to find and be able to work with the orientation of the apriltag. For each apriltag detected in an image or video stream, the rotation matrix and translation matrix of the apriltag are provided and I believe I these represent the orientation of the apriltag. However, as a proof of concept for this, I have attempted to draw a line from the center of the apriltag to its top (in its native orientation), and I am having issues doing this. I have extracted the Euler angles based on a function that I found online, and have attempted to draw a line starting from the center of the apriltag and extending from there at each of the Euler angles, but have gotten no good results. I have also attempted to calculate an "endpoint" which is displace 50 pixels from the center of the apriltag (in its x-axis), and then rotate that point around the origin using the same rotation matrix as the apriltag, but also got no good results with this. I am probably doing something wrong. I have included my code below. Please help.

Image of the detected apriltag and attempt to draw an orientation line: https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7plp.png

````
import numpy
import numpy as np
import cv2
from pupil_apriltags import Detector
import mathutils
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow

numpy.set_printoptions(linewidth=500)

camera_matrix = numpy.array([[645.00185337, 0, 304.75823489], [0, 646.18621837, 253.75317465], [0, 0, 1]])
fx = camera_matrix[0][0]
fy = camera_matrix[1][1]
cx = camera_matrix[0][2]
cy = camera_matrix[1][2]
camera_intrinsics_vector = [fx, fy, cx, cy]

def rot_matrix_to_euler(R):
    y_rot = numpy.arcsin(R[2][0])
    x_rot = numpy.arccos(R[2][2]/numpy.cos(y_rot))
    z_rot = numpy.arccos(R[0][0]/numpy.cos(y_rot))
    y_rot_angle = y_rot *(180/numpy.pi)
    x_rot_angle = x_rot *(180/numpy.pi)
    z_rot_angle = z_rot *(180/numpy.pi)
    return (x_rot_angle,y_rot_angle,z_rot_angle)

image = cv2.imread("apriltag.png")

bw_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

detector = Detector()
detections = detector.detect(bw_image, estimate_tag_pose=True, camera_params=camera_intrinsics_vector, tag_size=0.076)

for detection in detections:

    center = detection.center.astype(numpy.int32)
    cv2.circle(image, (center[0], center[1]), 3, (0, 255, 0), -1)

    corners = detection.corners.astype(numpy.int32)
    cv2.polylines(image, [corners], True, (0, 255, 0), thickness = 2)

    orientation = numpy.array([50, 0, 0])
    orientation = numpy.transpose(orientation)
    # endpoint = numpy.matmul(detection.pose_R, orientation).astype(numpy.int32) * 20
    orientation_line = numpy.matmul(detection.pose_R, orientation)

    euler_angles = rot_matrix_to_euler(detection.pose_R)

    # endpoint = numpy.array( [center[0] + int(orientation_line[0]), center[1] - int(orientation_line[1]) ] )
    endpoint = numpy.array( [center[0] + int(numpy.cos(euler_angles[0]) * 100), center[1] - int(numpy.sin(euler_angles[0]) * 100) ] )

    cv2.line(image, (center[0], center[1]), (endpoint[0], endpoint[1]), (0, 0, 255), 2)
    # cv2.line(image, (center[0], center[1]), (center[0] + endpoint[0], center[1] + endpoint[1]), (0, 0, 255), 2)

    # print(detection.pose_R.shape)
    # print(detection.pose_t)
    # print(orientation.shape)
    # print( numpy.matmul(detection.pose_R, orientation)  ) 

    # print(rot_matrix_to_euler(detection.pose_R))

cv2_imshow( image )```
````

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if I understood your problem exactly but you can use this code to start with. Following functions draw a pose and the cube above the tag and you can further use it to what you need to do.

These functions have been defined in the Apriltag library. You can edit the opoints array to change the dimension of the lines.

Hope it helps :D

```
def draw_pose(self,overlay, camera_params, tag_size, pose, z_sign=1):
    opoints = np.array([
        -2, -2, 0,
        2, -2, 0,
        2, 2, 0,
        2, -2, -4 * z_sign,
    ]).reshape(-1, 1, 3) * 0.5 * tag_size

    fx, fy, cx, cy = camera_params

    K = np.array([fx, 0, cx, 0, fy, cy, 0, 0, 1]).reshape(3, 3)

    rvec, _ = cv2.Rodrigues(pose[:3, :3])
    tvec = pose[:3, 3]

    dcoeffs = np.zeros(5)

    ipoints, _ = cv2.projectPoints(opoints, rvec, tvec, K, dcoeffs)

    ipoints = np.round(ipoints).astype(int)

    ipoints = [tuple(pt) for pt in ipoints.reshape(-1, 2)]

    cv2.line(overlay, ipoints[0], ipoints[1], (0,0,255), 2)
    cv2.line(overlay, ipoints[1], ipoints[2], (0,255,0), 2)
    cv2.line(overlay, ipoints[1], ipoints[3], (255,0,0), 2)
    font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
    cv2.putText(overlay, 'X', ipoints[0], font, 0.5, (0,0,255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
    cv2.putText(overlay, 'Y', ipoints[2], font, 0.5, (0,255,0), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
    cv2.putText(overlay, 'Z', ipoints[3], font, 0.5, (255,0,0), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)

def _draw_cube(self,overlay, camera_params, tag_size, pose,centroid, z_sign=1):

    opoints = np.array([
        -10, -8, 0,
        10, -8, 0,
        10, 8, 0,
        -10, 8, 0,
        -10, -8, 2 * z_sign,
        10, -8, 2 * z_sign,
        10, 8, 2 * z_sign,
        -10, 8, 2 * z_sign,
    ]).reshape(-1, 1, 3) * 0.5 * tag_size

    edges = np.array([
        0, 1,
        1, 2,
        2, 3,
        3, 0,
        0, 4,
        1, 5,
        2, 6,
        3, 7,
        4, 5,
        5, 6,
        6, 7,
        7, 4
    ]).reshape(-1, 2)

    fx, fy, cx, cy = camera_params

    K = np.array([fx, 0, cx, 0, fy, cy, 0, 0, 1]).reshape(3, 3)

    rvec, _ = cv2.Rodrigues(pose[:3, :3])
    tvec = pose[:3, 3]

    dcoeffs = np.zeros(5)

    ipoints, _ = cv2.projectPoints(opoints, rvec, tvec, K, dcoeffs)

    ipoints = np.round(ipoints).astype(int)

    ipoints = [tuple(pt) for pt in ipoints.reshape(-1, 2)]

    for i, j in edges:
        cv2.line(overlay, ipoints[i], ipoints[j], (0, 255, 0), 1, 16)
```